# Implementing external widgets in WordPress sites

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've been trying to add the generated widget code for walk score and great schools in a WordPress site and haven't had much luck. I installed the plugin Script n Styles and hoped that if I split up the code and put the JavaScript in the plugin's location for the page it would render the widgets, but no such luck. It appears to almost render the GreatSchools widget, but the map doesn't load still.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var ws_wsid = 'ga431dbc8ecbb4bc8a2c1f3599ba30081';
var ws_address = '1060 Lombard Street, San Francisco, CA';
var ws_format = 'tall';
var ws_width = '400';
var ws_height = '500';
</script><style type='text/css'>#ws-walkscore-tile{position:relative;text-align:left}#ws-walkscore-tile *{float:none;}</style><div id='ws-walkscore-tile'></div><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.walkscore.com/tile/show-walkscore-tile.php'></script>

<!-- School Finder Widget starts here --> <style type="text/css"> div#GS_schoolSearchWidget { border: solid 4px #999999; border-bottom-width: 20px; background-color: #FFF; width: 742px; position: relative; font-family: Arial, Arial, sans-serif; }  div.GS_widget_innerBorder { border: solid 1px #000000; }  div.GS_widget_footer { height: 40px; padding: 0 5px 0 15px; }  div.GS_widget_footer img { margin-top: 8px; float: left; border: 0 }  div.GS_seo { float: right; text-align: right; width: 120px; margin-top: 3px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; }  div#GS_schoolSearchWidget a, div#GS_schoolSearchWidget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }  div#GS_schoolSearchWidget div.GS_seo a, div#GS_schoolSearchWidget div.GS_seo a:hover { color: #666; font-size: 10px; }  div.GS_getWidget { position: absolute; bottom: -17px; right: 8px; }  div#GS_schoolSearchWidget div.GS_getWidget a, div#GS_schoolSearchWidget div.GS_getWidget a:hover { color: #0066B8; font-size: 11px; } </style> <script type="text/javascript"> function GS_updateSEOLinks(cityName, stateName, stateAbbr) { var cityLink = document.getElementById('GS_city_SEO'); var stateLink = document.getElementById('GS_state_SEO');  var cityUrl = GS_replaceAll(cityName, "%27", "'"); cityUrl = GS_replaceAll(cityUrl, " ", "_"); cityUrl = GS_replaceAll(cityUrl, "+", "_"); cityLink.href = "http://www.greatschools.org/city/" + cityUrl + "/" + stateAbbr; stateLink.href = "http://www.greatschools.org/modperl/go/" + stateAbbr; if (cityName == "New York" && stateAbbr == "NY") { cityLink.innerHTML = cityName  + " City schools"; stateLink.innerHTML = stateName + " State schools"; } else if (cityName == "Washington" && stateAbbr == "DC") { cityLink.innerHTML = cityName  + ", DC schools"; stateLink.innerHTML = ""; } else { cityLink.innerHTML = cityName  + " schools"; stateLink.innerHTML = stateName + " schools"; } }  function GS_replaceAll(strSource, strMatch, strReplace) { var rval = strSource; var index = rval.indexOf(strMatch); while (index != -1) { rval = rval.replace(strMatch, strReplace); index = rval.indexOf(strMatch); } return rval; } </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.greatschools.org/res/js/s_code.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.greatschools.org/res/js/externalTracking.js"></script> <div id="GS_schoolSearchWidget"> <div class="GS_widget_innerBorder"> <div id="widget"> <iframe class="greatschools" src="http://www.greatschools.org/widget/schoolSearch.page?searchQuery=94536&amp;textColor=0066B8&amp;bordersColor=000000&amp;lat=37.564144&amp;lon=-122.00418&amp;cityName=Fremont&amp;state=CA&amp;normalizedAddress=Fremont%2C+CA+94536&amp;width=740&amp;height=368&amp;zoom=13" width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> </div> <div class="GS_widget_footer"> <a href="http://www.greatschools.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.greatschools.org/res/img/widget/poweredby_logo.gif" alt="Powered by GreatSchools"/></a> <div class="GS_seo"> <div class="GS_city"><a href="http://www.greatschools.org/california/fremont/" target="_blank" rel="follow follow" id="GS_city_SEO">Fremont schools</a></div> <div class="GS_state"><a href="http://www.greatschools.org/california/" target="_blank" rel="follow follow" id="GS_state_SEO">California schools</a></div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="GS_getWidget"> <a href="http://www.greatschools.org/schoolfinder/widget/customize.page">I want this widget for my site</a> </div> </div> <script type="text/javascript"> pageTracking.pageName = "SchoolFinder Widget External"; pageTracking.hierarchy = "Widgets,SchoolFinder,6409421.20161224131721.294344"; pageTracking.server = "www.greatschools.org"; pageTracking.send(); </script> <!-- School Finder Widget ends here -->
```

I would really appreciate some feedback on how to add external javascript widgets in a wordpress page. Thank you in advance.

Update: It appears that the widgets do show up but when viewing the page in the Chrome browser it is being blocked as an unauthenticated script, so you have to allow the script to run. Is there anything to add in the WordPress environment to not trigger it as a possible unsafe script, and automatically run the script when loading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is part of Googles new(ish) CORS policy. You can try a simple fix for this, by removing `http:` from the script src links, so for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.greatschools.org/res/js/externalTracking.js"></script>
```

would instead be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.greatschools.org/res/js/externalTracking.js"></script>
```

If the site serving the script has an ssl certificate, this will then tell the browser to request it using the same authentication as the page (https). If the remote server does not have an ssl, you may run into the same problem.

---

The other problem is CORS itself (Cross Origin Request Policy).

In order to enable off site scripts, you need to pass a header that allows them. This can be done in php as such:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

In your specific case, this can be placed in your functions.php file, or alternately in a custom plugin (which will enable you to change your theme without breaking functionality). I would suggest doing it in a custom plugin personally.

---

It should be noted that Chrome in particular has gotten extremely finicky about this lately, and has actually made a lot of people angry by putting forth this change with no really effective way of disabling it, which has affected quite a lot of integrated pages in devices like routers and such where they use a legacy admin template and cannot effectively change them to conform with Chrome's new standards.